# OpenCV's cascade classifier not utilizing full power of the CPU

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I'm using OpenCV's cascade classifier for detection, however my CPU utilization never goes above 50% yet the application runs only at ~8 FPS so there should be a lot more room for improvement. I've installed OpenCV with TBB. My own program doesn't use any multithreading, it's only on OpenCV's part (detectMultiscale function). All CPU cores are at around 40%. I've tried setting the program's priority to realtime, but that didn't help. Could there be a bottleneck of some sort I am not aware of?

**Build details:**

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 IDE. Currently using these optimizations: Optimization: Maximize Speed (/O2), Inline Function Expansion: Default, Enable Intrinsic Functions: Yes (/Oi), Favor fast code (/Ot), Omit frame pointers: Yes (/Oy), Enable Fiber-Safe Optimizations: No, Whole Program Optimization: Yes (/GL). I'm on Windows 7 64bit, built the program on release mode as 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have an intel processor with hyperthreading technology. (2 threads per core), and TBB is smart enough to use only one thread per core (usually it's better than with two). And the operating system reports half the available power.

**EDIT**

if you want to modify the classifier by yourself, you can call setNumThreads(4); and then map affinities, and you will have 100% per core, instead of the average 80%, as explained in comments

What you see is the difference between marketing stuff (8 cores!!) and the truth(~3 cores)

Comment: Indeed, I have an Intel processor with hyperthreading. Using Process Explorer to check the CPU usage, the graph looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/7oy6r.jpg

Comment: It seems TBB is using 2 threads per core, but as your graph proves, it's worse with it than witohut it. Check this impressive article about hyperthreading http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=6

Comment: Thanks for the article. I couldn't turn hyperthreading off in the BIOS, so I tried messing around with setting affinities in the task manager, that didn't help though. I built OpenCV without TBB, but that decreased the program's performance. Could RAM be a bottleneck? A bit off-topic, but when I build the same program with Visual Studio 11, I get around a 20% performance gain.

Comment: There is no need to tune it. This is what your processor can do - and it's equivalent to working on 4 cores. You cannot make it faster than those 40% per thread, which is equivalent to 80% per core - that's it.

Comment: Oh, if you want to modify the classifier by yourself, you can  call setNumThreads(4); and then map affinities, and you will have 100% per core

Comment: In my case, the call to detectMultiscale() is using  nearly 100% cpu. can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the option which allows OpenCV to be built with TBB support in CMake.

Comment: It's built with TBB support. All of the cores are at ~40%.

Comment: Are you building in Release mode (i.e. with all optimizations on)? What platform are you on?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 IDE. Currently using these optimizations: Optimization: Maximize Speed (/O2), Inline Function Expansion: Default, Enable Intrinsic Functions: Yes (/Oi), Favor fast code (/Ot), Omit frame pointers: Yes (/Oy), Enable Fiber-Safe Optimizations: No, Whole Program Optimization: Yes (/GL). I'm on Windows 7 64bit, built the program on release mode as 64 bit.